# Bootstrap navbar fixed right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, nav

I am trying to create a navigation bar menu, with dropdowns etc, using the excellent bootstrap 3 navbar system.  I want the window glued to the right hand side of the screen, so that blank space appears to the left when the screen is expanded.  When the screen contracts, I want it to have the standard collapse behaviour, so that the menu items are replaced by a toggle icon.  Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peterrr73/n3ocdm7w/4/) for it.

```
<div class="header" style="width:850px; margin-left:auto">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Textual Communities</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Public Communities <span class="caret"></span></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">My Communities <span class="caret"></span></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Log in or register <span class="caret"></span></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
       </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Now, this is **almost** ok. If you expand the window, then indeed white space appears to the left and the menubar is glued to the right edge.  But, a problem:

- If you contract the window, the menu items disappear, fine, but you do NOT see the nice icon on the right indicating that you can toggle the menu so it reappears on the left, stacked vertically.

It seems the problem is that the width setting on the surrounding div (necessary so that margin-left:auto will push the div to the right) conflicts with the bootstrap behaviour. So you don't get to see the toggle menu icon. If you remove the style="width:850px; margin-left:auto" from the surrounding div, you will see that the nice toggle icon comes and goes as you contract and expand the window.  But then, you lose the stuck-to-the-right behaviour.

So here's the question.  It seems the villain is the width setting on the surrounding div.  But I don't see how to get margin-auto (or anything else) to work without setting a width on the element. Any ideas? I've tried out various things, floats, etc, but nothing seems to work.

**Update** A few more experiments, and I can see that the width setting is pushing the toggle icon off the screen. How do I stop this...? using position maybe?

Answer (score 0):

As a quick way to address this without touching much of the code you can add `right: 550px;` to the `.navbar-toggle` class which will move the button over closer to your main title text. You can see [your updated Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/n3ocdm7w/9/).

**UPDATE**

Ok similar to the other answer try adding your media query like this instead:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
    .header {
        width:auto !important;
    }
    .navbar-header{
        background: red;
}
```

The background color is just there for a visual reference and can be removed. [Updated Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/n3ocdm7w/10/).

Comment: Not a great solution.  first problem: the toggle icon should be fixed to the right hand pane; it is not with this.  Second: this is sensitive to the window width and would need resetting for each menu

Answer (score 0):

Try setting below css. If you wish to use header with `width:850px` property for desktop, so rewrite it for devices. http://jsfiddle.net/n3ocdm7w/11/

```
@media only screen and (max-width:760px){
    .header{
        width:100%!important;
     }
}
```

And remove `aria-expanded="false"` from toggle button, then it will work.

Comment: Same problem, though it is better than the last attempt as it does keep the icon to the right hand pane.  It would need resetting for each menu... I think there is a missing } at the end of this too.